# How to get the actual subclassed NSManagedObject from CoreData

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I created a subclass of NSManagedObject. When I fetch it, an object of NSManagedObject class is returned not my subclass.

How do I get the NSManagedObjectContext to return an object of my class instead of NSManagedObject class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, there's a field for that

[image]

[image: Turns out, there's a field for that]

Comment: Note: If you create your subclass by creating a new file while you have the Entity objected selected in the model, Xcode will do this for you.